# In John 8:36, is ὄντως ἐλεύθεροι or ἐλευθέρα more appropriate when referring to females?

Tags: greek, john

I’m designing a church graphic for a women’s study, and was wondering if the “free indeed” in John 8:36 works better to write as ὄντως ἐλεύθεροι or ὄντως ἐλευθέρα while referring to the phrase as females. Or does the ἐλεύθεροι work in this context since it is neutral?

Comment: The way the apostle John wrote it, is how it is to be written. All scripture is written in such a way that it is applicable to all who read it - as it has been written. ἐλεύθεροι is the nominative masculine plural [see Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/8-36.htm).

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

In the question of concord in Greek, that is, agreement to masculine or feminine, the masculine form is given priority when an adjective or participle, for example, refers to people among which are men and women.

So the masculine form refers to both male and female, the feminine form (you would want to use the plural form, -αι and not the singular form -α) would refer to "only women".

You can see this happening (masculine form when both a male and female are in question) in Lk 2:33

καὶ ἦν ὁ πατὴρ αὐτοῦ καὶ ἡ μήτηρ θαυμάζοντες ἐπὶ τοῖς λαλουμένοις περὶ αὐτοῦ.

Here his father and mother were amazed (participle in masculine plural).

So you would do best to keep the text as it is. It can refer to both men and women, not only men. The feminine form would refer to only women.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough response, Daniel! Appreciate it much!